# Dictionary not being cast while calling Swift function from Objective C

Tags: objective-c, swift, dictionary, nsnumber

I am calling a swift function from objective c using bridging. Also passing an NSMutableDictionary with key-value pairs. One value (op_status) although intact on the calling side goes to null when received. Attaching code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *offlineRequestData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
soId, @"soId",
AddNoteScreen, @"screen",
NotesOperation, @"operation",
jsonBlob, @"jsonBlob",
createdDate, @"created_datetime",
[NSNumber numberWithInt:OperationNotSynced], @"op_status",
@"", @"sync_datetime", nil];
```

// OperationNotSynced is an enum.

--

// On the Swift side:
// Inside Swift function that uses the dictionary

```
newRecord.op_status = valuesDictionary["op_status"] as? NSNumber
```

op_status gets null here.

Also, printing out valuesDictionary["op_status"] gives me optional(int value) and unwrapping prints the value. But it does nt get cast to NSNumber.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since `op_status` is an `Int?`, you can conditionally cast it to an `Int` and create an `NSNumber` with an initializer.

```
if let opStatusInt = valuesDictionary["op_status"] as? Int {
    newRecord.op_status = NSNumber(value: opStatusInt)
}
```

Comment: op_status should be NSNumber? rather than Int? right ? as I am doing this?: 
[NSNumber numberWithInt:OperationNotSynced].

Comment: Swift is automatically casting it to an `Int` for you. Swift wants you to use its newer Foundation types over outdated Objective-C types like `NSNumber`. Unfortunately, things like CoreData still rely on `NSNumber`. Sometimes you have to play these games with the Swift compiler/type system.

Comment: Tried it, Looks like valuesDictionary["op_status"] is not being cast to Int? also. Printing it out shows Optional(1) (or other values) though.

Comment: If you print out `valuesDictionary["op_status"].dynamicType`, what does it say?

Comment: Optional<AnyObject>

Comment: Fixed it. Looks like it is being received as a String?, so did this:  
`if let opStatusInt = valuesDictionary["op_status"] as? String { newRecord.op_status = NSNumber(integer: Int(opStatusInt)!) }`   
Looks like too much code for something trivial though.